# Python Multiprocessing IndexError

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to parallel process some file by reading chunks and process each chunk by using multiprocessing libraries. Following is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import islice
import traceback

#Produce key value pairs (Date, Market_Share*Market_Share)
def Map(L):
    results = []
    for w in L:
        temp = w.split(',')
        Date = temp[0]
        Share = float(temp[1][:-1])
        ShareSquare = str(Share*Share)
        results.append((Date,ShareSquare))
    return results



if __name__=='__main__':
    pool = Pool(2)
    f = open('C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Project/Optiver/atchm_9450.csv','r')
    fw = open('C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Project/Optiver/marketshare.csv','w')
    f.readline()
    while True:
        next_n_lines = list(islice(f,16))
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        else:
            l = pool.map(Map,next_n_lines)
    f.close()
    fw.close()
```

However, it produces index out of range error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trial.py", line 29, in <module>
    l = pool.map(Map,next_n_lines)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The list object I passed into the Map function is something like ['6/26/2014,68.90\n', '6/27/2014,68.84\n', '6/30/2014,68.80\n'....]

It works correctly when there is no parallelism involved (pool is not invoked).

What possibly causes this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, only those two lines can raise this exception:

```
    Date = temp[0]
    Share = float(temp[1][:-1])
```

Try to check that w have enough data.

Comment: Thx. The problem is that the Map function doesn't actually needs to do the for loop iteration because the pool.map already has mechanism to break the list into chunks and iterate through each chunk in parallel. So the argument of Map function should be an element instead of a list. I initially thought that pool.map divides the list into a few 'sub list' and these sub lists should be passed into the function.